# Not able to grab 3D models in oculus

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working on a unity oculus project in which I need to instantiate a 3D Models and interact with them by using Oculus Grabables with my hand.

Here, the 3D models are not asset bundles as it is instantiates from Database.

Here I have used TriLib 2 as a third party library to load asset from database.

The problem arises here is that 3D modles are perfectly instantiated in my scene but I am not be able interact with them with oculus.

I have made a custom script in which I am adding required components of oculus to grab that instantiated 3D models.

At last I am not be able to grab that 3D models.

Can you please help me to get out of this..?

Comment: Does your object have proper collision meshes? And is your object on a layer that ignores raycast?

Comment: Hello Boyfinn,I am adding colliders on objects after they are downloaded in the scene. So all the required components are added through script by using add component method.

Comment: How about the gameobject's layer? Have you checked that the layer has inter collisions enabled between the object's layer and the raycaster's (controller's) layer?